# Learning Visual Studio 2008 from Scratch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I've never used any version of Visual Studio. I know some SQL and some C, C++, Pascal, etc., from the "olden days" way of programming.
My new job requires me to use Visual Studio. I'm just lost at the "jargon" and at where to find things and finding my way around it.

How do I get started?

Thanks.

Comment: It's just an IDE: editor plus compiler plus debugger plus some other tools.  Start by writing a hello world app in the language of your choice.  When you can compile and link it, and step through it in the debugger, you've mastered 99% of what you need to know.

Comment: Why don't you go with vs2010? I there any special reason for vs2008?

Comment: I work at a company and they didn't move to VS 2010 yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165079%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is helpful in getting started to get familiar with Visual Studio 2008. Documentation is very helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Through your link eventually I got to this: http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PsodPlayer?author=kate-gregory&name=vs2010-gettingstarted-01&mode=live&clip=0&course=vs2010-gettingstarted which is superb. Well explained, to the point and clarifies confusions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good place to start with walkthroughs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165079(v=vs.80).aspx

I think that youtube would also be a great place to check for tutorials on how to get started using the IDE.

Comment: Your link was the same as edmastermind29's, but I gave him the "check" because he posted a bit earlier than you.  BTW, I had checked YT, it just doesn't bring up based on what I need, but based on their choice of KWs., etc.

Comment: Very well, i noticed you found Pluralsight and they are a great resource. 
Another option that i've found to be useful is just playing around with Visual Studio. I find new stuff that i never knew about just from going through the menus and options and messing around with it to see what does what.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is google. You can start searching for concepts:

- solutions
- project types/project configurations
- compiling
- linking
- adding files/resources/classes/etc.
- debugging
- debugging tools and windows

Comment: Thanks Luchian, I did that before asking the question here.